# apt-get install not connecting to server when trying to install libssl-dev on Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, apt

I'm running this command as root:

```
apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Here is the response:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libssl-doc libssl1.0.0 zlib1g-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libssl-dev libssl-doc zlib1g-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libssl1.0.0
1 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 129 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,656 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,570 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
0% [Connecting to security.debian.org (2607:ea00:101:3c0b::1deb:215)] [Connecting to ftp.us.debian.org (2610:148:1f10:3::89)]
```

Then nothing happens. Things just hang. I can ping out from the server so I definitely have an internet connection.

Here is my `sources.list` file:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main

deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org jessie main non-free
deb-src http://www.deb-multimedia.org jessie main non-free

deb http://packages.linuxmint.com debian import
```

**Edit #1**
I recently installed the `IO::Socket::SSL` perl module via cpanm. I doubt this would make a difference but making note of this just in case.

**Edit #2**
Found the problem. It was a router setting issue: https://superuser.com/questions/1174054/cant-ping-ipv6-server-on-internet-from-debian-running-on-virtualbox/1174093#1174093

Answer (score 2):

Force `apt-get` to use IPv4:

```
apt-get install -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true libssl-dev
```

To make it permanent:

```
echo 'Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/42ipv4
```

Comment: Hmm, still hangs. But this worked: http://askubuntu.com/questions/574569/apt-get-stuck-at-0-connecting-to-us-archive-ubuntu-com

Comment: I take that back the advice there didn't work. Getting these errors now:

  404  Not Found [IP: 128.61.240.73 80]
Err http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main libssl-dev amd64 1.0.1k-3+deb8u4
  404  Not Found [IP: 128.61.240.73 80]
Err http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main libssl-doc all 1.0.1k-3+deb8u4
  404  Not Found [IP: 128.61.240.73 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/o/openssl/libssl1.0.0_1.0.1k-3+deb8u4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 128.61.240.73 80]

etc.

Answer (score 0):

`libssl1.0.0` comes from the Security Repository but your lines

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
```

look Ok

Debian has a page which is often referred to people -

```
 https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian/
```

I would be very suspicious of you using

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com debian import

deb-multimedia is not recommended by Debian, but it seems to be Ok for the moment
```

If you do not need source code you do not need the lines starting deb-src.

Instead of using a static Repository you could try Debian Redirector

instead. It switches to whatever is faster.

You could change your sources list to

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org jessie main non-free
```

...then do (as Root)

```
apt update
apt-upgrade
```

...and try again

Comment: Made change to `sources.list` per your recommendation. Then did apt-get upgrade. Everything looked like it was working for a bit then it got stuck again when it hit an IPV6 address.
..
                                                                 
Get:13 http://www.deb-multimedia.org/ jessie/main deb-multimedia-keyring all 2016.8.1 [10.7 kB]                                                                                                                 
3% [Connecting to security.debian.org (2610:148:1f10:3::73)

Comment: Try installing the keyring again "After you have added the necessary line in /etc/apt/sources.list the first package to install is deb-multimedia-keyring.

apt-get update
apt-get install deb-multimedia-keyring" - http://www.deb-multimedia.org/

Comment: Didn't help. It gets stuck every time I try to download from an IPV6 network.

FYI, I'm running my Debian install in VirtualBox. My WAN is IPV6. My internal network is IPV4. Not sure if that could be an issue.

Comment: OK, this has something to do with my network. ping6 ipv6.google.com doesn't work.

Comment: Found the problem:

http://superuser.com/questions/1174054/cant-ping-ipv6-server-on-internet-from-debian-running-on-virtualbox/1174093#1174093

There goes a morning.

Answer (score 0):

I contributed to an article here https://askubuntu.com/questions/993609/error-installing-zlib1g-dev/1376130#1376130

down at the bottom, I have the right jesse links and show the right commands you need to enter for apt-get upgrade and update. Once you follow those instructions, apt installs will be a piece of cake.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/394946)